# Replace block of lines in file with Linux/Unix Command

Tags: linux, unix, command

Could you please help for a command that can do on a file:

Input -1:

```
/*
* Copyright (c) 1992-2013 Some comp, Inc and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
* Some comp PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
* Author: aaaa
* DateCreated:   aaaa
* Last Modified By: aaaa
* Modified Time:  aaaa
* File Version: aaaa
* File Path: aaaa
*/
```

All above lines should delete and replace with

```
/*
* Copyright (c) 1992-2013 some comp, and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
* some comp PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
* Author: bbbb
* DateCreated:   bbbb
* Last Modified By:  bbbb
* Modified Time:  bbbb
* File Version:  bbbb
* File Path:  bbbb
*/
```

My opinion is, first delete from '/*'   to '*/' first occurrence or delete till */ from starting of file. 
And after, replacing with second block of lines at the top of file.

Comment: what's the main difference between the two pieces of text?I don't see much difference, except Inc in the first and 'S' replaced with 's' in the second piece of text!

Comment: Now I can see the difference!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions with sed and awk. Gawk has a function called gsub for substituting text.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file is called `filename`. Save the new text without the first and last lines (i.e. from "* Copyright..." to "* File Path...") in `newcopyright`. Then:

```
sed -e '/Path/ r newcopyright' -e '/Copyright/,/Path/d' filename
```

This will send the new file to standard output (i.e. your screen). You can redirect it to a new file, or if you want to modify the file in place, you can do this:

```
sed -i '.save' -e '/Path/ r newcopyright' -e '/Copyright/,/Path/d' filename
```

Comment: Hi Beta, /Path mean my file path you are saying.

Comment: @Kumar: No, "/Path" is "/Path". In the file, at the end of the text you want to replace, is a line that begins "* File Path: ". The `sed` command uses that as a landmark. Are you having trouble with this command? If so, I can walk you through it.